# What plant is this and how can I keep it alive?

Tags: identification, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations, succulents

I am hoping to get some help with my succulent. I recently bought a little pot full of a few different types of succulents. It was already looking a little bleak, but one of the succulents seems to be getting a lot worse. They started out looking like little green sticks, but now the tops are starting to turn brown and the leaves are shriveling and falling off. The leaves are very fragile now, and they can easily fall off if I gently brush them.

I am not sure what type of succulent it is.  My friend told me it might be Crassula Tetragona. I have also not had many succulents, so I am not sure if it looks like this because it needs more water or if it is something else. I have been watering it by soaking the soil and letting it dry, but I have watered it a couple times before it was dry because I was afraid that it was dying because it needed more water. I just checked the soil and it is still wet, so I am not sure what else I should do. Thank you so much for your help!!

[image: My dying succulent]

Comment: I think your friend is right, Crassula tetragona or miniature pine tree. Likes to be dry more than wet. Tim's suggestion to change soil will help greatly; think positive drainage, no wet feet.

Answer (score 2):

I can't identify the species, but this plant has had far too much water. I see it is planted in sphagnum moss with aborbs and holds water, when it lays against the stem it makes it permanently damp. I zoomed in and it looks like there is mold growing on the soil, another sign of less-than-ideal environment. I can't tell from the picture, but does the pot have a drain hole in it? If not, repot into a pot that does have good drainage.

Speaking of repotting, try to get some cactus/succulent soil and use that. It won't hold water as long and has lot of air spaces which most succulents need.

That plant doesn't look good, but if you can get it in to a better situation and don't water it for a week or so, it may pull through.

If it survives, water it when it's almost dry.

Good luck!